# Docker on OSX: How to start boot2docker in one shell and use it in another

Tags: macos, docker, init

After initialising with `boot2docker start`, only a specific terminal can then use docker commands. No other tabs, no other programs.

In Emacs I'd like to execute the build and run commands in a new process every time they are called upon. The fact that I'd have to boot2docker init every single time makes this impossible.

I'm also getting really tired of exporting every single time and I know other people must be extremely frustrated as well, so I'm hoping someone found a solution?

Comment: add boot2docker init to your .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

if `boot2docker` is on your path in each shell, then you can

```
eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
```

as per https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md#tls-support

Comment: The `eval` is redundant. You can simply do `$(boot2docker shellinit)` directly in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

First check that the VM is ok to run as far as VT being enabled goes - a surefire way to do this is just to open Virtualbox manually (yes, not very "docker" of me... humph!) and find the VM.

Sidebar:
If you mistakenly ran boot2docker init as root or another user you will see those entries in there too... remove the unneeded VMs?

Anyways, look at settings for your boot2docker-vm and see if there is a "hint" at the bottom of the settings window letting you know if something is not configured right.

Like, for instance if VT-d isnt enabled, or something like you don't have the right amount of RAM allocated for the VM or the VM's video card.

Next, start the VM from within Virtualbox.

For me, after I properly adjusted memory settings the last issue was:

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).
```

So I looked here:

```
sudo sysctl -a | egrep VMX

machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX SMX EST TM2 SSSE3 CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 XSAVE
```

So, if you have VMX show up here then you need to enable it in your bios (hackintosh) or you can enable it by updating your EFI firmware or through some other absurd method:

https://communities.vmware.com/message/932263